# Android, нужна помощь с таблицей. API 29

Tags: java, android

Необходимы отобразить в приложении большую таблицу, поэтому через TableLayout не вариант. Пробовал картинкой засунуть в приложение, используя RelativeLayout, т.к. приложение будет использоваться на разных устройствах этот метод отметается, ибо она жутко не красиво расплывётся.Может существует метод динамического заполнения, используя данные из бд в recyclerview????

Comment: Как вариант, можно еще генерировать Html и показывать в webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать сделать "список из списков" и его можно динамически заполнять. Это просто recyclerview и всё.

Посмотри эту библиотеку:
https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/README.md

Там есть то о чем я говорил. Надеюсь это решит твою проблему.